# Ruby - Win32Console - using colors changes encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding, colors, rubygems

I have recently installed gem Win32Console for my program. The program has Polish “interface”, which includes Polish special characters. Which works fine for every

```
puts "Ciekawym polskim słowem jest: żółć"
```

However, using escape characters in order to colorize the test (which works) seem to change the encoding and Windows 7 CMD displays such diacritic marks incorrectly:

```
green = "\e[1;32;40m"
puts "#{green}Ciekawym polskim słowem jest: żółć"
```

Honestly, with my limited knowledge of hot Ruby treats different encoding, I don't really even know where to start - is that a problem with Ruby, Win32Console or Command Prompt itself?

Answer (score 0):

Windows console does not support ASCII escape sequence (`\e[...`) at all. ([ANSI escape code - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS)).

Comment: So I guess the ruby gem responsible for coloring strings in CMD is the one responsible for the change in encoding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the gem I installed. I later found out that Ruby 2.0 and higher has built-in support for escape codes and it works just fine with UTF-8.